# WinDbg single step exception not firing

Tags: exception, windbg, breakpoints

I am debugging an exe (x86) in WinDbg because it is crashing on my computer, the devs provide no support and it's closed source.

So far I found out that it crashes because a null pointer is passed to `ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection`.

I'm trying to find the source of that null pointer and I've reached a point (my "current point") where I have absolutely no idea where it was called from. I tried searching the area of the last few addresses on the stack, but there were no calls, jumps or returns at all there.

The only thing I have is the last dll loaded before the crash, which is apparently also long (at least a few thousand instructions) before my current point.

I can't just set a few thousand break points, so I thought single step exceptions could help (I could at least print `eip` on every instruction, I don't care if that would take days).

But I can't get the CPU to fire the exception! After loading the exe, I enter the following in the debugger:

```
sxe ld:<dll name>
g
sxe sse
sxe wos
r tf=1
g
```

The debugger breaks for the loaded dll where I want it to, but after the second `g`, the program just runs for a few seconds before hitting the crash point, not raising any single step exception at all.

If I do the same without the first two lines (so I'm at the start point of the program), it works. I know that `tf` is set to zero every time a SSE is fired, but why doesn't it fire at all later in the program?

Am I missing something? Or is there any other way I could find the source of that null pointer?

Comment: have you tried the kv command to list stack and arguments when it crashes ?

Comment: @KjellGunnar Sure, but as it prints a few addresses and symbols, it also provides me with the warning `WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.` I've been using `kd` since.

Comment: What is your goal? Investigating bugs in 3-rd party code without symbols and source code is futile. Even if you find problem, you won't be able to code up a meaningful fix for it. My suggestion is you create a crash dump using command `.dump -ma` in WinDbg and send it over to the product owner. The crash dump should be enough for them to find and fix the problem.

Comment: Well, I guess you're right. Will do that tomorrow and just hope the devs care enough.
But still that does not explain why the single step exception was not firing, which I'd kinda like to know just because I'm curious...

Comment: It is quite possible (I am hypothesising here) is that command `g` sets `tf=0` automatically, since it is meant to continue execution of the program till the next breakpoint. That is what command `t` is for -- it sets `tf=1` in current thread context.

Comment: Looks like S.T. 's hypothesis is correct. I think you should be using "gc" here instead of g.
this command causes execution to resume in the same manner that was occurring before the breakpoint was hit (stepping, tracing, or free execution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`g` is not the command for single stepping, it means "go" and only breaks on breakpoints or exceptions.

To do single stepping, use `p`. Since you don't have the source code, you cannot do instruction-stepping on source code level, meaning that you have to do it on assembly level. (Assembler instruction stepping should be default, it not enable it with `l-t`.) Depending on how far you need to go, this takes time.

Above only answers the question as it is. The open question is, like pointed out in the comments already, what will you do to mitigate that bug? You can't simply create a new critical section nor do you know which existing critical section should be used in that place.

Comment: Since the program works on most computers, but crashes on some others (including mine) I was assuming that there is code to instanciate the critical section somewhere, but that code simply fails (or is skipped due to a failed assertion, which is basically the same). If that were the case, I was hoping to find out what exactly is causing the failure, which I suspect to be either an undocumented software dependency or an undocumented driver/hardware incompatibility.

Anyway, this answers the original question, thank you.